# Why container_of macro prevents other parts of the kernel from modifying the unique fields of your structure?

Tags: linux, macros, kernel

I was looking for information on internet and finally I know how the macro works and what it do, overall after reading http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html
At the finish, it says that it prevents other parts of the kernel from modifying the unique fields of the structure used to control the subsystem's code.
Could you explain me why?

Sorry by my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [webpage](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) you linked to had the following example:

> ```
> struct i2c_driver {
>         char name[32];
>         struct device_driver driver;
> };
> ```

The Linux device driver core is only going to care about the `struct device_driver` and not about the specifics related to `struct i2c_driver`.  This is the abstraction level that the device driver core cares about.  Therefore in the Linux device driver core a pointer to a `struct device_driver` is going to be passed around, not a pointer to a device specific struct.  If you have a `struct device_driver` you cannot determine without some other knowledge what type of struct contains the `struct device_driver`.

To make an analogy using object oriented programming terminology: `struct i2c_driver` is a child "class" of `struct device_driver`.  In object oriented programming you cannot go from a parent type (e.g. `struct device_driver`) to a child type (e.g. `struct i2c_driver`), without some other information, such as information gained by using a `typeof` operating or something similar.
Similarly, if some piece of code has a pointer to a `struct device_driver` unless it makes some assumption about what the pointer is pointing to, it will not try to access any of the `struct i2c_driver` fields.

Note that "prevent" really isn't the word I would pick because at least in my opinion "prevent" imply that there is some compile-time or run-time protection that will stop this from happening.  This is not the case.  Instead **well written** code that adheres to the conventions set out with regards to abstraction of device drivers will not manipulate the "child" object fields.  There is nothing that prevents someone from doing this however, beyond breaking the abstraction.

Finally, the sentence before the one you are referring to sheds some light on this:

> The **driver core only passes in the type of driver structure registered with it**, so this type of manipulation is safe. This also prevents other parts of the kernel from modifying the unique fields of the structure used to control the subsystem's code.

Basically, reiterating that the driver core only cares about `struct device_driver` not anything device specific.

Comment: Thank you by your quck respose. I would like to ask you if it is possible that the kernel assing a variable in the same direction than the new structure. I mind it is not reserved. Or you could have a varible assigned on the same direcction, could not you? Thats what I dont understand well.